# Why are the eigenvalues of a Markov matrix bounded within the unit circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Define a Markov matrix as $P \in M_n([0, 1])$ such that for every row $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, $\sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij} = 1$.

It's commonly noted the eigenvalues of $P$ lie within the unit circle, i.e., $\sigma(P) \subset \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| \leq 1 \}$.
This fact is important because it is necessary to show that a diagonalizable Markov chain will converge to a steady state distribution, but I could not find a proof for this bound.

I eventually proved this using the Gershgorin circle theorem, but I'm curious what other approaches exist for proving this?

Comment: See [Perron−Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

Comment: @nejimban Perron-Frobenius only applies to irreducible non-negative matrices, no? Is it extensible to reducible Markov chains?

Comment: Not directly, indeed. Anyway irreducibility is a necessary condition for convergence to a (the) steady state distribution.

Comment: @vivek See [this note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices_2) in the Wikipedia article; in particular, for non-negative but reducible matrices it still implies the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G(P) = \cup_{i=1}^n \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z - P_{ii}| \leq \sum_{j \neq i} P_{ij} \}$ be the union of the Gershgorin circles of $P$.
By the definition of the Markov matrix, the radius of every Gershgorin circle is bounded such that $\sum_{j \neq i} P_{ij} \leq 1$.
Additionally, every Gershgorin circle is centered at $1 - \sum_{j \neq i} P_{ij}$.
Therefore, every circle is constrained within the unit circle, implying that $G(P) \subset \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| \leq 1 \}$ as well.

Finally, by application of the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), $\sigma(P) \subset G(P) \subset \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| \leq 1 \}$.

Comment: Unrolling Gerschgorin's circle theorem proof: let $(\lambda,x)$ be an eigenpair, that is $x\neq0$ and
$$\sum_{j=1}^nP_{ij}x_j=\lambda x_i,\qquad1\le i\le n.$$
Taking absolute values leads to
$$|\lambda||x_i|\le\sum_{j=1}^nP_{ij}|x_j|\le\|x\|_\infty\sum_{j=1}^nP_{ij}=\|x\|_\infty$$
for every $i$, thus $|\lambda|\|x\|_\infty\le\|x\|_\infty$, implying $|\lambda|\le1$ (because $x\neq0$).

Answer (score 2):

using Schur Triangularization $P= UTU^*$.
$P\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$ so $P$ has an eigenvalue of 1. Let $\lambda_m$ be the maximum modulus eigenvalue of $P$, with modulus of $1+\delta$, for some $\delta \geq 0$.

$1+k\delta \leq \vert \lambda_m \vert^k \leq \big \Vert T^k\big \Vert_F = \big \Vert P^k\big \Vert_F = \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (p_{i,j}^{(k)}})^2\leq  \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n p_{i,j}^{(k)}=\sum_{i=1}^n(1) = n$
*justification:*  Bernouli Inequality, unitary invariance of Frobenius norm, triangle inequality, $P^k\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$

This holds for all $k\in \big\{1,2,3,...\big\}\implies \delta =0\implies \vert \lambda_m \vert= 1$